# Angular route params in service

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-router-params

I need to get route param in my service

```
import {Inject, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';
import {ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd, Router} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'any'
})
export class LocationService {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    console.log('ddd ', );

    this.router.events.subscribe((data) => {
      if (data instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        console.log('this.route.snapshot.params[\'city\']; ', this.route.firstChild.snapshot.params['city']);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

in component that

```
this.router.events.subscribe((data) => {
  if (data instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    console.log('this.route.snapshot.params[\'city\']; ', this.route.firstChild.snapshot.params['city']);
  }
});
```

works correctly but in the service `city` is undefined

If I provide Location service in the component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-city-chooser',
  templateUrl: './city-chooser.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./city-chooser.component.scss'],
  providers: [LocationSerivce]
})
```

my service calls twice (i use my service in different component)

How to get route params in my service?

---

UPD: project has two modules!!!
BasicModule and DashboardModule

Comment: This is wrong approach never do that, why you need params in service you can pass param to service via component and do whatever you want in service.

Comment: @KamranKhatti exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass params into service method and do whatever you want, getting route params inside service is not a good approach we should avoid it.

```
export class LocationService {
 constructor() {}
 
 doSomething(param) {
  // write your logic here
  console.log(param)
 }
```

In component

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private service: LocationService) {
   const params = this.route.snapshot.params['city'];
   this.service.doSomething(params)
}
```

Hope this works.

Comment: @Karman Khatti, is the correct way to use this.route.firstChild on the parent component? I have two modules and in each module i have main component, each page on my app use that service and i need init it on each page for different url if i put it in the new browser tab

Comment: so i want to init my service in main module component

Comment: I dont know how you implemented if this.route.firstChild works for you go for it its just matter of getting params value